# What is the regular expression to remove whitespace inside brackets?

Tags: java, regex

I am writing a program in Java to accept queries. If I have a query like

```
insert    
into  
abc      values   (    e   
, b    );
```

...what regular expression can I use to convert that into:

```
insert into abc values(e,b);
```

...or:

```
insert:into:abc:values(e,b);
```

Actually I want to know how I can I write a regular expression to remove whitespace within brackets only.

Comment: May the brackets nest? If so, you're screwed (a Perl wizard may manage it, but the result won't be nice or maintainable and I wouldn't bet on it being portable to less sophisticated regex engines).

Comment: Lets keep it simple. That there are no nested brackets.

Comment: This isn't exactly a solution to your problem, since you've already got some pretty great responses up above, but, if you're ever at a stand-still for something like this, I find that there are some great testers online -- I use [this one](http://regexpal.com) the most, since it's real-time, and has a nice reference sheet on the right side.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming correctly balanced parentheses, and no nested parentheses, the following will remove all whitespace within parentheses (and only there):

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("\\s+(?=[^()]*\\))", "");
```

It transforms

```
insert    
into  
abc      values   (    e   
, b    );
```

into

```
insert    
into  
abc      values   (e,b);
```

**Explanation:**

```
\s+      # Match whitespace
(?=      # only if followed by...
 [^()]*  # any number of characters except parentheses
 \)      # and a closing parenthesis
)        # End of lookahead assertion
```

Comment: Perfect one. Thanks a lot.  I will use again replaceAll("\\s+",":"); to get the result and execute query

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see you don't need RegEx for this. That should work:

```
yourString.replaceAll("\n", " ").replaceAll("( ","(").replaceAll(" )",")").replaceAll(", ",",").replaceAll(" ,",",");
```

Comment: That's not a solution. As for the following string it will not work where
( e , b ) ; can contain multiple spaces.

Comment: For the first string he posted my solution worked. But he edited his example string.