# Regex to remove spaces between '[' and ']'

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

I have been breaking my head on this for sometime now.
In javascript I have a string expression where I need to remove the spaces between '[' and ']'.

For example the expression can be :-

```
"[first name] + [ last name ] + calculateAge()"
```

I want it to become :-

```
"[firstname] + [lastname] + calculateAge()"
```

I tried something from the following [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731097/what-is-the-regular-expression-to-remove-whitespace-inside-brackets) for square brackets but didn't quite get there. How do I make the regex in that question, work for square brackets too?

Can anyone help?

Thanks,
AJ

Comment: I don't think you can do this in one step. You have to extract the contents of the brackets, remove spaces from that, and then substitute that back in.

Comment: Can the brackets be nested? If so, you can't do it with a JavaScript regex. If not, no problem (if brackets are always correctly balanced).

Comment: It wont be nested as of now.  So looks simple.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If brackets are always balanced correctly and if they are never nested, then you can do it:

```
result = subject.replace(/\s+(?=[^[\]]*\])/g, "");
```

This replaces whitespace characters if and only if there is a `]` character ahead in the string with no intervening `[` or `]` characters.

**Explanation:**

```
\s+       # Match whitespace characters
(?=       # if it's possible to match the following here:
 [^[\]]*  # Any number of characters except [ or ]
 \]       # followed by a ].
)         # End of lookahead assertion.
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
"[first name] + [ last name ] + calculateAge()".replace(/\[.*?\]/g, function(string) {
    return string.replace(/\s/g, '');
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fwmFC/)

Comment: Thanks Arun. Can you explain a bit about the above expression?

Answer (score 0):

Slight adaptation so you can use in in [Visual Studio Code] or [SSMS] with [SQL] queries, remember to hit the regex option on the find/replace dialog

```
\s+(?=[^[\]]*\])
```

[image: SSMS Find/replace dialog]

Note - screenshot shows the spaces being replaced with "_"

Answer (score -5):

You can use this

```
"[first name] + [ last name ] + calculateAge()".gsub(/\s+/, "")
```

This works in ruby

Comment: Did you even test that? The question is about JavaScript, not Ruby, and in Ruby, you get `[firstname]+[lastname]+calculateAge()` as a result.