# Python remove spaces in between braces

Tags: python, regex

I am using re but I am not having any luck. I want to know how to remove spaces in between braces. For example

I have this string

```
     i want to go to the[ super mall ](place)
```

You see the the space in "[ super mall]"?

What can turn this string into

```
      i want to go to the [super mall](place)
```

I would appreciate any help I can get on this thanks.

Comment: Can braces be nested?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex to remove spaces between '\[' and '\]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644159/regex-to-remove-spaces-between-and)

Comment: What's with the space after `'the'`, where does it come from?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming braces are balanced and cannot be nested.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'i want to go to the[super mall](place) [ for real    ]'
>>> re.sub('\[\s*(.*?)\s*\]', r'[\1]', s)
'i want to go to the[super mall](place) [for real]'
```

> It doesn't work for multiple ones. like i want to go to the [ super mall ](place) and [ cheese mall ](place)

I think it does.

```
>>> s = 'i want to go to the [ super mall ](place) and [ cheese mall ](place)'
>>> re.sub('\[\s*(.*?)\s*\]', r'[\1]', s)
'i want to go to the [super mall](place) and [cheese mall](place)'
```

Comment: There is a space after `the`

Comment: @HarshalParekh oh, didn't catch that.

Comment: @HarshalParekh But since OP did not mention that I assume it's a typo in the question.

Comment: It doesn't work for multiple ones. like  i want to go to the [ super  mall ](place) and [ cheese mall ](place)

Comment: @MattQuaine see edit.

Comment: @MattQuaine could you make it work?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to removing the space around the brackets you also want to transform `the[` into `the [`

To handle this and remove any number / type of spaces around the text in brackets, you can do the following

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'i want to go to the[  super mall  ](place)'
>>> re.sub(r'(\w)\[\s+(.*?)\s+\]', r'\1 [\2]', 'i want to go to the[  super mall  ](place)')
'i want to go to the [super mall](place)'
```

We can look at the first two arguments to `re.sub` in further detail (the last argument is just the string to operate on).

First we have this regex `r'(\w)\[\s+(.*?)\s+\]'`

- `(\w)\[` matches a word and a bracket and stores the word for use later using parentheses, (matches `the[` in the original string)
- `\s+` matches one or more whitespace characters (matches  in the original string)
- `(.*?)` matches any text within the brackets and spaces and stores this text for use later using parentheses (matches `super mall` in the original string)
- `\s+\]` matches one or more whitespace characters and the closing bracket (matches `]` in the original string)

From that regex, we have stored two strings (`the` and `super mall`) and matched this entire substring `the[  super mall  ]`.

Next we have the template to replace that entire substring with: `\1 [\2]`. this uses the stored strings from earlier to replace `\1` and `\2` respectively.

Comment: `the[` becomes `the [`. Your code does not do that.

Comment: You should avoid overwriting built-in objects like `str`.

Comment: @blacksite thanks, I've changed that, I've also added the code to replace `the[` with `the [`

Answer (score 0):

You can use groups and backreferencing to solve this:

```
string = 'i want to go to the[ super mall ](place)'
re.sub('\[ (.+) \]', '[\g<1>]', string)
```

Here I am assuming that you always have atleast one character, padded with one space on each side, within the brackets.

This will give you 
`'i want to go to the[super mall](place)'`

*See re docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub*