# Javascript - Detect certain characters within a string and replace content between those characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm kind of a newby with Javascript, and regex in general and would appreciate all help I can receive!

Consider the following command: [Doesn't matter where it's executed]

**/Ban Tom {Breaking The Rules} 5**

What I need to do is detect the string between {}, replace the spaces with underscores there(_) and remove the curly brackets around the new string.
Example of outcome:

**/Ban Tom Breaking_The_Rules 5**

Thanks,
Tom.

Comment: It'll help us help you if you post what you've tried (even if you haven't gotten very far---show us your regex).

Comment: As mentioned in the post, I'm quite a nooby regex. I tried a different approach using .split("{") and .split("}") but that didn't get me too far :(

Comment: Here's an interactive tutorial: http://regexone.com/. Go through a few pages and come back with what you've gathered might be useful toward your problem. You'll learn a lot more that way! (And the answer will make more sense too :-) Then, we're happy to polish it up for you, iron out any syntax issues, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need a RegEx as this can be achieved by just normal javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var str = "/Ban Tom {Breaking The Rules} 5";
    var oldStr = str.substring(str.indexOf("{"), (str.indexOf("}") + 1));
    var newStr = oldStr.replace(/ /g, "_").replace("{", "").replace("}", "");

    alert(str.replace(oldStr, newStr));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use string.toCharArray()  and parse through the array for matching { and spaces to replace them.

Comment: Could you elaborate more, please?

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = '/Ban Tom {Breaking The Rules} 5';  
var patt=new RegExp('{[^}].*}',i);  
var res = patt.exec(str);  

//include res check here.....  
var newStr = res[0].replace(/ /g, '_');  
newStr = newStr.replace(/[{}]/g, '');  
str = newStr.replace(res[0], newStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// The Message:
var foo = "/Ban Tom {Breaking The Rules} 5";

// Replace Whitespace in braces:
foo = foo.replace(/\s+(?=[^\{\}]*\})/g, "_");

//Replace braces with nothing:
foo.replace(/[\{\}]/g,""):
```

First regex explanation:

```
\s+        // Match whitespace
(?=        // If followed by:
[^\{\}]*   // Any number of characters except braces
\}         // The closing brace
)          // End of the lookahed
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731097) provided most of the information, I just adapted it to javascript.