# How to remove specific characters in a string *within specific delimiters*, e.g. within parentheses

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

In the string

```
my_string = 'abcd (ef gh ) ij'
```

I need to remove the spaces only when they appear within parentheses, resulting in:

```
my_clean_string = 'abcd (efgh) ij'
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640001/how-can-i-remove-text-within-parentheses-with-a-regex) suggests how to remove all parentheses text entirely via `re.sub(r'\([^)]*\)', '', my_string)`, however I do not know how specify the removal should only be applied to whitespaces `' '`.

Is there a regexpr (or simple python) solution that does this without looping through each character expressly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one general way that will work for nested parenthesis as well:

```
In [27]: my_string = 'abcd (  ()e(e w  )f ) gh'

In [28]: re.sub(r' \(\s+|\s+\)', lambda x: x.group().strip(), my_string)
Out[28]: 'abcd(()e(e w)f) gh'
```

If you want to remove spaces even between words you can play around with  [look-arounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) ;-):

```
In [40]: my_string = 'abcd (  ()e(e w  )f ) gh'

In [41]: re.sub(r'\s+(?=[^[\(]*\))|((?<=\()\s+)', '', my_string)
Out[41]: 'abcd (()e(ew)f) gh'
```

Comment: Can you remove also spaces between words within the parentheses?

Comment: @Kasramvd split and join works for your nested regex also. Update it.

Comment: @MYGz [Now you have two problems](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) :-)

Answer (score 1):

This will remove spaces in front and behind the words inside the parenthesis.

```
import re
my_string = 'abcd (   ef dfg dfg  ) gh'
print re.sub('\(\s*(.*?)\s*\)', lambda x: ''.join(x.group().split()), my_string, re.DOTALL)
```

Output:

```
abcd (efdfgdfg) gh
```

Comment: I need to remove all spaces, included between words, example `abcd (efdfgdfg) gh` in your case

Comment: @Pythonic Updated.

Comment: @Pythonic for considering newlines you can use `re.DOTALL`

Answer (score 0):

a solution without using regex,

```
my_string = 'abcd (ef ) gh'
str_to_replace = my_string[my_string.find('(')+1:my_string.find(')')]
out = my_string.replace(str_to_replace,str_to_replace.replace(' ',''))
```

Result

> abcd (ef) gh

Answer (score 0):

Relating from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731097/what-is-the-regular-expression-to-remove-whitespace-inside-brackets),

```
re.sub("\\s+(?=[^()]*\\))", "", my_string)
```

Comment: This won't work with strings like  `'abcd (  ()e(e w  )f ) gh'`